# Run-time error '438' While looping through every charts of a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a macro to go through every charts of a sheet to hide any data label with a #N/A value/caption (I use two series in my charts, one green and one red depending on an objective).

When I run this sub, I get this: "Run-time error '438' : Object doesn't support this property or methode

the code line where this happen is this one :
`For l = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabels.Count`

I've been look on the many other question/answer for this issue but every cases seems diferent when it comes to this kind of error.

Is there anyone with a better understanding of VBA that could pin point the problem?

```
   Sub LoopThroughCharts()
'PURPOSE: Loop through every graph in the a selected worksheet

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Annuel")
  For Each cht In .ChartObjects
    cht.Activate
    With ActiveChart
    For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
        For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
            For l = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabels.Count
               If .SeriesCollection.Points(j).DataLabels.Item(l).Caption = "#N/A" Then
                   .SeriesCollection.Points(j).DataLabels.Item(l).Delete
                End If
            Next l
        Next j
    Next k
   End With
  Next cht
End With

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head but I'm wagering that a single *point* object (e.g., `Points(j)` doesn't have a `DataLabels` collection. Try simply `.SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate over the `Points(j).DataLabels` because `Point` object doesn't have a `DataLabels` property.

Try this (modified to not *delete* the caption just use an empty string):

```
Dim cObj As ChartObject, cht As Chart, srs As Series, p As Integer
For Each cObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Set cht = cObj.Chart
    With cht
        For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
            If srs.HasDataLabels Then
                For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
                    If srs.Points(p).HasDataLabel Then
                        If srs.DataLabels.Item(p).Caption = "#N/A" Then
                            srs.DataLabels.Item(p).Caption = ""
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
```

Try deleting from a collection and you'll run in to errors unless you do it in reverse index (which is possible, but not necessary in this case when you can just use an empty string).

Also added some logic to ensure you don't hit error if a DataLabel has already been deleted (i.e., it's possible for `srs.HasDataLabel` to be `True` while it can be `False` for an individual `Point` in the series.

Comment: First thing i'll try tomorow at work! Thank you sir :)